# JS animation loop when returning to hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, hide, show

I have an element which I animate to move across the screen. From `left:-100px` to `left:screen-width`. I loop this 4 times.

When returning the element back to its original position `left:-100px`, I don’t want it to be seen moving across the screen (*from right to left*) really fast.

I tried to do it by hiding the element with `.hide()` and then showing it after a while (so that it has time to move back to its initial position). But this *doesn’t* work:

```
$('.snake-image').hide();
$('.snake-image').css('top', height / 2).css('left', currentPos);
setTimeout(function(){$('.snake-image').show();},1000);
```

Code:

```
$('body').append('<a href="#"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48552248/projects/covve/website/2015/public/images/snake.png" class="snake-image" style="position:absolute;top:0;" />');

function goRight(currentPos) {
  $('.snake-image').animate({
    left: currentPos
  }, 100);
}

function moveSnake() {
  while (currentPos <= width) {
    goRight(currentPos);
    currentPos += 20;
    console.log(width + " x " + currentPos);
  }
}

var currentPos,
    height = $(window).height(),
    width = $(window).width(),
    i = 4;

var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
  if (i > 0){
    currentPos = -100;
    $('.snake-image').hide();
    $('.snake-image').css('top', height / 2).css('left', currentPos);
    setTimeout(function(){$('.snake-image').show();},1000);
    moveSnake();
    i--;
    console.log('Interval 1');
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}, 100);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m0epjLym/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the animate [callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
triggered at the end of the animation, you can move your item back in the origina position and then call again the animation

`Fiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/xgknu376/

Comment: Thanks for this. I’m trying to add the `setInterval()` (`timeOut()` could also work) inside the animate callback somehow, so that it waits a bit before triggering animation again. But I can’t get it to work. It eats up two loops (4 and executes only 2).

Comment: i added a line to do that, same fiddle, you should use setTimeout instead of setInterval, in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.snake-image').animate({'opacity': 0}, 0);
$('.snake-image').animate({'top': height / 2}, 0).animate({'left': currentPos}, 0).delay(1000).animate({'opacity': 1}, 0);
```

The delay function will only work on items that are in the animation queue.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y995cts3/3/

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, a refactor should be done, as the code is messy :) Exploring ways to “improve” it.